# wine vs wine64 binary on 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: wine, 64-bit

Installing Wine provides me with two wine binary executables that I can use to run programs with: `wine` and `wine64`.

How do they differ and where should I use each of them?

Comment: "wine 32bitWinApp.exe" and "wine64 64bitWinApp.exe" ?

Comment: @Sadi But both ran a software (specifically, a game) which I'm not sure if it's 32-bit or 64-bit. Probably 32-bit though.

Comment: I don't have any experience or knowledge about this specific issue really (I use very few apps via Wine and they're all 32-bit), but I guess if you try "wine64 64bitWinApp.exe" and it doesn't work, then it must be 32-bit app, if it works, probably you should get better performance.

Comment: If both ran, as you said, then I'm at a loss :-( I'm also curious about the answer to this question. AFAIK wine-64bit is a different thing, but then what is this wine64 doing in our regular wine installation?

Comment: See: http://wiki.winehq.org/Wine64.